# How to make custom Folder/Album in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, artificial-intelligence

i am making a data acquisition app that will enable doctors to take pictures of skin diseases to be used later for AI/ML purposes, so my app will have a camera button to take a picture, and lets say 4 labels or buttons that name the disease (chickenpox, eczema etc) once the user takes the picture, he will click the corresponding button to label the image, what i want is all the images under one label are saved into a separate folder/Album with the same name as the disease.

i have made the interface with buttons and it does save the picture but in the photo gallery, I've googled a lot but was unable to find an exact solution as to how to make custom folder and save images to them. If anybody could help i would be really grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The func would be used to save the photo to specific folders within the app not the phone photo gallery. The fileName would be the name you give to the picture and the fileFolder would be what type of disease eg. Chickenpox.

```
 func SaveImage(fileName: String, fileFolder: String, image: UIImage)
{
    var objCBool: ObjCBool = true
    let mainPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0];
    let folderPath = mainPath + "/Diseases/\(fileFolder)/"

    let isExist = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: folderPath, isDirectory: &objCBool)
    if !isExist {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: folderPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let imageName = "\(filename).png"
    let imageUrl = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("/Diseases/\(fileFolder)/\(imageName)")
    if let data = image.pngData(){
        do {
            try data.write(to: imageUrl)
            print("SAVED IMAGE")
        } catch {
            print("error saving", error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your implementation, can't find where in the app the images are stored

Comment: add  "Supports opening documents in place" & "Supports Document Browser" to your info.plist and you will be able to see the subfolder of your app within your device.